# getChildCount() and getChildAt() return zero for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to get a count of RecyclerView children. I've tried this:

```
myRView.getChildCount();
```

And this:

```
LinearLayoutManager lm = ((LinearLayoutManager)myRViews.getLayoutManager());
lm.getChildCount();
```

I need to get a child View at certain position so that's why I need this. If I call `getChildAt(index)` I never get any child View.

Both of these methods return 0. How else to get a child View from RecyclerView? My items appear correctly and everything is working fine. I am calling these methods after I create my adapter and set it to RecyclerView. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are calling those methods before layout is calculated.

When you set the adapter, the layout will happen in the next view tree traversal. You can consider adding a ViewTreeObserver.

Answer (score 7):

You could use your adapter getItemCount() function.

```
myRView.getAdapter.getItemCount();
```

Comment: Thank you but I still can't get a View with getChildAt() method.

Comment: Why do you need the view?

Comment: I really don't know, but since RecyclerView draws the views only when it's needed, it could be impossible to get certain child view. But maybe you could modify your adapter and create a function like onBindViewHolder and paint manually and on demand the view that you need.

Answer (score 5):

The function is called when the view is not ready that's why it returns zero, use post() method will help.

```
myRView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.show("myRView.post " + myRView.getChildCount());
            View childView = myRView.getChildAt(0);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

`getChildCount()` may return 0 if you forget to set LayoutManager to RecyclerView.

```
myRView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```